# condition after groupby: data science

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have a big df, this is a example to ilustrate my issue. I want to know from this dataframe whichs id by year_of_life are in the first percent in terms of jobs. I want to identify (i am thinking with a dummy) the one percent by years_of_life which has more jobs from the distribution.

for example

```
id  year  rap   jobs_c    jobs  year_of_life  rap_new
1   2009    0      300     10      NaN       0  
2   2012    0     2012     12      0         0   
3   2013    0     2012     12      1         1
4   2014    0     2012     13      2         1
5   2015    1     2012     15      3         1
6   2016    0     2012     17      4         0
7   2017    0     2012     19      5         0
8   2009    0     2009     15      0         1
9   2010    0     2009     2       1         1
10  2011    0     2009     3       2         1
11  2012    1     2009     3       3         0
12  2013    0     2009     15      4         0
13  2014    0     2009     12      5         0
14  2015    0     2009     13      6         0
15  2016    0     2009     13      7         0
16  2011    0     2009     3       2         1
17  2012    1     2009     3       3         0
18  2013    0     2009     18      4         0
19  2014    0     2009     12      5         0
20  2015    0     2009     13      6         0
.....
100 2009    0     2007     5       6         1
```

I want to identify (i am thinking with a dummy) the one percent by years_of_life which has more jobs from the distribution and then sum the jobs from those ids by year_of_life in the first percent

i try something like thi:

```
df.groupby(['year_of_life']).filter(lambda x : x.jobs> 
x.jobs.quantile(.99))['jobs'].sum()
```

but i have the following error

```
TypeError: filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ?

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['year_of_life']).jobs.apply(lambda x : x>x.quantile(.99)).fillna(True),'jobs'].sum()
Out[193]: 102
```

Comment: Mmmm, i am expecting a result that show me by each year_of_life the sum of jobs of the one percent observation with highest values of jobs